# inserting the same value into two different tables

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to insert into two tables for the same value, both actual_quote, in pdo, how would I go about this?    **it's only inserting to voters, not data**

```
<?php
$db_name = 'submissions';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname=submissions', $db_user, $db_pass);
$formtype = (empty($_POST['formtype'])) ? : $_POST['formtype'] ;
$poster = (empty($_POST['poster'])) ? : $_POST['poster'] ;
$actual_quote = (empty($_POST['actual_quote'])) ? : $_POST['actual_quote'] ;
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `data` (actual_quote, poster, formtype) VALUES (    :actual_quote, :poster, :formtype)");
$query->bindParam(':formtype', $formtype, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindParam(':poster', $poster, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindParam(':actual_quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->execute();
$query1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO voters (actual_quote) VALUES ( :actual_quote)") or die(mysql_error());
$query1->bindParam(':actual_quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query1->execute();
?>
```

I fixed it, i had to mess with the database

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Your ternary syntax is incorrect, you can't just say `empty($var) ? : $var`, you need to specify an empty value whether it be `''` or `null` e.g. `$formtype = empty($_POST['formtype']) ? null : $_POST['formtype'];`

Comment: @scrowler actually, it is correct and you can. When `$var` is *empty*, the result is `true`

Comment: @Phil noted - it may not be a correct solution in this example but good to know you can do that :)

Comment: I should have edited this, the issue is it's only inserting to voters, not data

Comment: are there any constraints on `voters` that aren't being satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

`or die(mysql_error());` ??? you are not supposed to mix mysql and PDO:

```
if(isset($_POST['formtype'], $_POST['poster'], $_POST['actual_quote'])){
//post data
$formtype = $_POST['formtype'];
$poster = $_POST['poster'] ;
$actual_quote = $_POST['actual_quote'] ; 

//credential
$db_name = 'submissions';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_host = 'localhost';

//connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname=submissions', $db_user, $db_pass);
//very very important
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

//data query
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `data` (actual_quote, poster, formtype) VALUES (:actual_quote, :poster, :formtype)");
$query->bindValue(':formtype', $formtype, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindValue(':poster', $poster, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindValue(':actual_quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->execute();

//voters query
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO voters (actual_quote) VALUES ( :actual_quote)");
$query->bindValue(':actual_quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->execute();
}
```